# Are unity games as performant as Unreal's?

Tags: unity, unreal-4, unreal

TLDR: I make both RPG and MMORPG, 3D, heavy games with big landscape. Both engines are very good, but which one produces games with more FPS assuming the quality was the same?

I've been using RPGmaker and Gamemaker a lot in the past.

Recently I've kept switching from UE4 to Unity and vice versa. I can't decide which one is better. Unity is more popular so its a huge + for unity.

However some people claim Unreal games are much faster because unreal codes in c++.

However, Unity now created something called DOTS thats supposed to be faster than c++

For example, this [site](http://www.begamedev.com/unity/how-to-make-rpg) says that Unity is better than ue4 especially for rpg, which is one of my fav genres

What are your thoughts? I need to know this to not spend months and years in wrong engine.

Comment: Performance is a massively broad subject and there are many things that each do well and not so well. There are a rediculous number of factors to take into account and couldn't possibly be answered in a single answer. Language (c#/c++) though doesn't have much to do with if. As both engines are C++ under the hood.

Comment: We don't answer "which technology should I use" questions on this particular site. Fortunately, you can get great gameplay, rendering, and performance out of both Unity and Unreal. Ultimately, the speed of your game is determined moreso by what you put in it and how you tune your own work than by the engine you choose.

Answer (score 2):

Both Unity and Unreal are capable of producing AAA quality games with high, stable framerates. How do we know? Because both have been used to make AAA quality games with high, stable framerates. This means that whatever performance differences there are are unlikely to form a sensible basis for deciding between engines, and remember that the time available to optimise performance is about as important for final performance as any underlying difference in the engine used.

That said, if you really, *really* care, Unreal gives you the source and Unity doesn't which means that you are able to boost the performance more in Unreal than in Unity because only one of them lets you tune the underlying engine to your specific game.